# User Attempts using Count

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I want to create a user attempts in my count using a condition. How can I do this kind of logic using conditions and where to put in my code below.
Example: If a user tries to login 3 times with the wrong input of user and pass, he will get a message of you have already reached login attempts

```
private void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var obj = new Usercontrols.SIMSMain();
        obj.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from admin_access where Username=@admin AND Password=@eyelab",conn);
        selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@admin", txt_username.Text);
        selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eyelab", txt_password.Text);
        SqlDataReader dataReader;   
        dataReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
        var count = 0;

        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            count = count + 1;
        }
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_username.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_password.Text))
    {
        MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Please input the Required Fields", "System Message:", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    }
    else
    {
        if (count == 1)
        {
            MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Login Successful", "System Message:", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            this.Hide();
            this.Parent.Controls.Add(obj);
        }
        else if (count == 3)
        {
            count++;
            MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Super Attempt", "System Message:", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        else
        {
            MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Invalid Username/Password", "System Message:", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
        }    
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: No sir , I already have username & password values in my Database, if user input values that don't match the values in my database it will go through to my else condition which is invalid user/pass

Comment: You increment your fail counter only when password and login match when you shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres your modified code, to handle attempts more than 3

```
Timer loginAttempsTimeOut;
Dictionary<string, int> loginAttempsPerUser = new Dictionary<string,int>();
Dictionary<string, DateTime> loginAttemptsViolated = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();
int TimeOutInMinutes = 15;

private void SetTimer()
{
    loginAttempsTimeOut = new Timer();
    loginAttempsTimeOut.Interval = 1000 * 60; // check timeout every 1 mins
    loginAttempsTimeOut.Enalbed = true;
    loginAttempsTimeOut.Tick += LoginAttempsTimeOut_Tick;
}

// set a timer, and if login timeout for each user is elapsed,
// allow user to try login again
private void LoginAttempsTimeOut_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(var user in loginAttemptsViolated.Keys)
    {
        loginAttemptsViolated.TryGetValue(user, out var date);
        TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now.Subtract(date);
        if(span.TotalMinutes > TimeOutInMinutes)
        {
            loginAttempsPerUser[user] = 0;
            loginAttemptsViolated.Remove(user);
            loginAttempsPerUser.Remove(user); 
        }
    }
}

private void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var obj = new Usercontrols.SIMSMain();
        obj.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from admin_access where Username=@admin AND Password=@eyelab", conn);
        selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@admin", txt_username.Text);
        selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eyelab", txt_password.Text);
        SqlDataReader dataReader;
        dataReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
        var count = 0;

        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            count = count + 1;
        }
        if(loginAttemptsViolated.ContainsKey(txt_username.Text))
        {
           MetroMessageBox.Show("Login attempts is more than 3.");
        }
        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_username.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_password.Text))
        {
            MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Please input the Required Fields", "System Message:", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
        else
        {
            if (count == 1)
            {
                MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Login Successful", "System Message:", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                this.Hide();
                this.Parent.Controls.Add(obj);
            }
            else if (count == 3)
            {
                count++;
                MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Super Attempt", "System Message:", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            else
            {
                //if user cannot login, increase login attempts
                if(!loginAttempsPerUser.ContainsKey(txt_username.Text))
                   loginAttempsPerUser.Add(txt_username.Text, 1);

                loginAttempsPerUser[txt_username.Text]++;
                if(loginAttempsPerUser[txt_username.Text] > 2)
                {
                    // if login attempts > 2 set a 15 min timeout till user 
                    // cant login
                    if(!loginAttemptsViolated.ContainsKey(txt_username.Text))
                       loginAttemptsViolated.Add(txt_username.Text, DateTime.Now);
                }
                MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Invalid Username/Password", "System Message:", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
            }
        }
        conn.Close();
    }

}
```

There is a timeout too, because if user violate the login count, then have to give another chance to him/her later(eg. 15 mins later).

Comment: if(span.TotalMinutes > timeOut) // where did you get timeOut ??
        {
            loginAttempsPerUser[user] = 0;
            loginAttemptsViolated.Remove(user);
        }

Comment: Edited my answer. It'd be timeOutInMinutes, that's already defined in the first rows.

Comment: I got an error to if (loginAttemptsViolated[txt_username.Text] != null) // System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: 'The given key was not present in the dictionary.'

Comment: Ok, now try it.

Comment: loginAttempsPerUser[txt_username]++; // Did you forget to input .text here ? coz i got this message cannot convert metro textbox to string
and also tried it it solve the problem error and already tried it, it stack to login attempts msgbox and i wait 2 mins and try to login the right input values and still stack to login attempts msgbox (nothing happen to timer?)

Comment: There are some mistakes for sure, but I can't write your program instead of you. 
I modified my code last time. I'd rather like to give you an idea, not the code exactly, but It should work now.

Comment: Yep, i know that and thank you sir for taking your time to it :)
It's okay now just added some logic to it

Comment: It's absolutely okey. :)

Comment: Can i ask a last question sir ? , after the messgbox login attempts i disabled my both textbox so the user cant do anything , after the timer finish it automatically enabled both textbox

Comment: I can't see any question sir.

Comment: I don't know the code im gonna used to that logic coz im not the one who construct it.

Answer (score 0):

You are already using `SqlDataReader.Read()` a simple else can handle the case where no result are return. 
You are already using `SqlDataReader.Read()` a simple else can handle the case where no result are return.

```
int failAttempt  = 0;

private void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // Step 1: Check if inputs are valid
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_username.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_password.Text))
    {
        MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Please input the Required Fields", "System Message:", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        return;
    }


    // Step 2: Check if there is one user with this password/login
    var obj = new Usercontrols.SIMSMain();
    obj.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from admin_access where Username=@admin AND Password=@eyelab",conn);
    selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@admin", txt_username.Text);
    selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eyelab", txt_password.Text);
    SqlDataReader dataReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();

    int numberMatch=0;

    while(dataReader.Read()){
        numberMatch++;
    }
    conn.Close();


    // Step 3: Fail Handle

    if(numberMatch==1){ // Success
        failAttempt  = 0;

        MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Login Successful", "System Message:", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        this.Hide();
        this.Parent.Controls.Add(obj);
    }
    else { // Fail 0 or more than one
        failAttempt ++;

        if (failAttempt == 3)
        {
            MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Super Attempt", "System Message:", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        else
        {
            MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Invalid Username/Password", "System Message:", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Code edit to show all the algo, int failAttempt  = 0; is defined outside of the function so it doesnt get reset at every click

Comment: I have Eddited my answer I didn't understand that you were counting the read to know how many matching result you had. I had this logic so only uniq match count as sucess.

Comment: Yes sir , i tried the first one and it is wrong logic, but now it's solved my problem. Thank you very much sir !

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your count variable as a Global Variable.

```
    int count = 1;
    private void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var obj = new Usercontrols.SIMSMain();
        obj.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from admin_access where Username=@admin AND Password=@eyelab", conn);
        selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@admin", txt_username.Text);
        selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eyelab", txt_password.Text);
        SqlDataReader dataReader;
        dataReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
        var counter = 0; //to check if there is data
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            counter++;
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_username.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_password.Text))
        {
            MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Please input the Required Fields", "System Message:", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
        else
        {
            if (counter == 1)
            {
                MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Login Successful", "System Message:", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                this.Hide();
                this.Parent.Controls.Add(obj);
            }
            else if (count == 3)
            {
                count++;
                MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Super Attempt", "System Message:", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            else
            {
                count++;
                MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Invalid Username/Password", "System Message:", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
            }
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to declare a static counter which increments with every user Login click. If the same user is attempting and the counter is 3 then show the message eg"You have exceeded your limit.". Below is your revised code.

```
          private static int loginCounter;
          private static string UserName;

          private void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                var obj = new Usercontrols.SIMSMain();
                obj.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from admin_access where Username=@admin AND Password=@eyelab",conn);
                selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@admin", txt_username.Text);
                selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eyelab", txt_password.Text);
                SqlDataReader dataReader;   
                dataReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
                var count = 0;

                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    count = count + 1;
                }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_username.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_password.Text))
            {
                MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Please input the Required Fields", "System Message:", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
            else
            {
            if (count == 0 && UserName == txt_username.Text)
            {
           loginCounter += 1;
             }
            if(loginCounter  >= 3)
            {
     MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "You have exceeded maximum login attempts.", "System Message:", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
            }
UserName == txt_username.Text
                if (count == 1)
                {
// Here reset the login counter, since the password is right
loginCounter = 0;
UserName = "";
                    MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Login Successful", "System Message:", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    this.Hide();
                    this.Parent.Controls.Add(obj);
                }
                else if (count == 3)
                {
                    count++;
                    MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Super Attempt", "System Message:", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
                else
                {
                    MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Invalid Username/Password", "System Message:", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
                }    
            }

            conn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: How does this work when 2 users are trying to login nearly simultaneously?